# Trouble importing and using react-native-gifted-charts in TypeScript Expo App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I recently set up a simple TypeScript app using Expo CLI with the command `expo init appName` using the TypeScript template. The app was functioning well until I tried to integrate the react-native-gifted-charts library to include a bar chart. Unfortunately, I encountered an issue that I'm having trouble resolving.

Here's the code snippet where I attempted to use the BarChart component from react-native-gifted-charts:

```
import { BarChart } from "react-native-gifted-charts";
...
...

<View style={styles.chartContainer}>
          <BarChart
            data={Data}
            width={300}
            height={200}
            chartConfig={{
              backgroundGradientFrom: "#1E2923",
              backgroundGradientTo: "#08130D",
              fillShadowGradient: "#45E355",
              fillShadowGradientOpacity: 0.8,
              color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
              labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
              style: {
                borderRadius: 16,
              },
            }}
            style={{
              marginVertical: 8,
              borderRadius: 16,
            }}
          />
        </View>
```

When I attempt to use the above code, I encounter an error message that points to the NativeModules.js file. However, upon inspecting the NativeModules.js file, I noticed that it appears to contain TypeScript content, even though its file extension is .js. This discrepancy is puzzling to me and is causing several error lines within the file.

I'm unsure if I'm using the BarChart component incorrectly or if there's something else going on. I am seeking clarification on the following points:

How can I correctly integrate and use the react-native-gifted-charts library, specifically the BarChart component, in a TypeScript-based Expo app?

Why is the NativeModules.js file being automatically generated with a .js file extension while containing TypeScript-like content?
Are there any suggestions on resolving the issue with the NativeModules.js file and the related errors?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a development build according to the [expo doc](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/)

Comment: Please share the code with some solution you have tried